# conver string number to float

Tags: ruby

I have this string:

```
"3,8"
```

I would like to get a float like this:

```
3.8
```

Comment: I suggest you to use Babai method. Because it takes less time to execute when compared to other methods. If you need to verify please use Benchmark library to benchmark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) method:

```
"3,8".tr(',', '.').to_f   # => 3.8
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

`"3,8".sub(/,/, '.').to_f`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you actually have a comma as a decimal point, you could do this:

```
"3,8".sub(",", ".").to_f
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also works

```
Float("%d.%d" % "3,8".split(","))
```